# Effect of theoretically infinitely heavy body on spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, curvature, singularities

What is the effect of theoretically infinitely heavy massive body on spacetime? And what happens when it moves and/or rotates/spins along a path?

Comment: To quote Wheeler:  *"Spacetime tells matter how to move; matter tells spacetime how to curve. "* - Put 'infinity' in there and your question essentially becomes *"how does an infinite mass move in an infinitely curved spacetime?"* which smells a lot like the old *irresistible force meets immovable object*.

Comment: Actually if the universe is infinite, which may be the case, with infinite spatial extension (an open of flat universe), it may have an infinite energy. So it could just be our universe.

Comment: No infinite mass = no singularities.  'Infinitely warped' leads to geometry; how much can you bend something?  Maximum of 360 degrees.

Comment: This question delves into; What happens inside a black hole?  Theories about singularities, other dimensions, or other universes.  Rotates, leads to frame stretching.  Interesting.